# Disable resharper line break in a section of code?

Tags: resharper

Using inspection, I can easily disable and restore resharper reformatting settings. For instance like this:

```
// ReSharper disable SuggestVarOrType_BuiltInTypes
int i = 1;
// ReSharper restore SuggestVarOrType_BuiltInTypes
```

So.. is there any way to do the same to line breaking, so that I can have long lines in special places in my code and still have resharper break the others?

Basically, I guess, I ask for the secret word to put in place of "SuggestVarOrType_BuiltInTypes" above :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using these comments:

```
    // @formatter:wrap_lines False
    {the code block for which you would like to disable wrapping long lines}
    // @formatter:wrap_lines restore
```

By the way, you may find out most of the formatter comments on your own using this way: 
`select needed code block | hit the Alt+Enter shortcut | hit the "Right arrow" key on the "Format selection" item in the menu to open a submenu | hit "Configure"` -> it will open the new window which shows you all formatter settings which affect the code block.

[image]

Then you are welcome to change all the settings you like and click on `Save as comments` button -> you will get everything you need as comments around the code block.